# How to sort this Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I am trying to sort my class here. My code is a follows

```
public class Row
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public object this[string index]
    {
        get { return _data[index]; }
        set { _data[index] = value; }
    }
}
```

I have added it into Observable collection like

```
ObservableCollection<Row> RowList = new ObservableCollection<Row>();
```

In my Final Output I get

```
RowList[0]._data[0].Key = "Column 1"
                   .Value = "23"
          ._data[1].Key = "Column 2"
                   .Value = "Not Important"
          ._data[1].Key = "Column 3"
                   .Value = "Not Important"

RowList[1]._data[0].Key = "Column 1"
                       .Value = "11"
          ._data[1].Key = "Column 2"
                       .Value = "Not Important"
          ._data[1].Key = "Column 3"
                       .Value="Not Important"

RowList[2]._data[0].Key = "Column 1"
                   .Value = "8"
          ._data[1].Key = "Column 2"
                   .Value = "Not Important"
          ._data[1].Key = "Column 3"
                   .Value = "Not Important"
```

Now I want to Sort `Column 1` values. I can use Linq I tried using

```
foreach (RowList _r in RowList.OrderBy(p => p.Column1))// I am not sure if this approach is right
{

}
```

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Do you have any specific concerns? Note that this is not changing the dictionary at all - it's just creating a new sequence which has the same elements, but in a different order.

Comment: I just want to sort the elements and then maybe add into another observable collection

Comment: Actually, looking at it, that code wouldn't even compile at the moment. Your `Row` type doesn't have a `Column1` property. Note that you're not trying to sort a dictionary - you're trying to sort a *collection* of dictionaries.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes the columns are added as `Keys` dynamically..But how can i acheive my goal ..is ther any other alternative way ???

Comment: It's not clear what your goal really is, I'm afraid. When you present code that won't compile, and don't explain whether you're *only* interested in the values for a particular column or whether you're trying to sort *by* column1, or what you want the end result to be, it's very hard to help you.

Comment: These values are binded to Grid So i want to sort all the Column1 values...does that make it simple ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40359/discussion-between-user168139-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by any expression. It does not have to be a simple property access (which you seem to be assuming intuitively):

```
RowList.OrderBy(p => (AppropriateDataTypeHere)p.Keys["Column1"])
```

The cast is necessary because you cannot compare two `object` variables. You could write a custom `IComparer<object>` which can do that and which would implement your comparison rules.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for `.OrderBy(r => r[0].Key)`?

Answer (score 0):

You and the other answerers are quite close to the solution. It is in fact:

```
RowList.OrderBy(p => p["Column1"])
```

The `Row` class has an indexer property that takes a string (not an int).

You also should consider @usr's hint on the types of the values.
In your example all values are strings. This means they are sorted as strings: `11, 23, 8`

To order them numerically you can either change the type of the values:

```
row[0]["Column1"] = 23; // <-- value is int
row[1]["Column1"] = 11;
row[2]["Column1"] = 8;
```

or convert them in the sort:

```
RowList.OrderBy(p => int.Parse(p["Column1"]));
```

Now the order is: `8, 11, 23`